# LIKE and NOT LIKE in MySQL do not match total number of rows

Tags: mysql, sql

For example, I have a 100 row table with a `varchar` column.

I run these queries:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM myTable WHERE myText LIKE '%hello%'
SELECT count(*) FROM myTable WHERE myText NOT LIKE '%hello%'
```

I am not getting a total count of 100. It is not picking up some of the rows for some reason. Why would this be happening?

Comment: Do you have any `NULL` values in your table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for `NULL` values, neither `LIKE` nor `NOT LIKE` will count these.

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible that some of the data in field do not have the word "Hello" in them. If you want to display all the row, just use

```
select count(*) from mytable;
```

without using where clause.

Comment: That's what `NOT LIKE` checks... Which is what the asker is trying to do: Count two kinds of records, ones that have `hello` and ones that don't...

Comment: Okay...I guess I was not that clear from the description. Thanks @TimLewis

Comment: Yes, the question wasn't explained in much detail, but essentially he wants to count two possible entries and total them, but they didn't equal the actual total, which shouldn't be possible.